# How to update version label dynamically in github actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions

In .github/workflows/build_and_test.yml I have a field `version_label`

```
version_label: 1.10
```

The value for this field is static now, means I have to update it manually every time when I deploy to server using GitHub actions. So I want to make it dynamic so that the value should be incremented automatically on every commit
like : `1.11 , 1.12, 1.13` and so on.

because if I don't change the version label `AWS EB Env` does not accept the deployment.

Comment: An option could be to use a script in your workflow to check and update this value automatically for you at each workflow run (as there probably isn't any native way, nor action, to do it for you at the moment).